# Abnormally high accuracy with repeated 10-fold CV and ordinal regression

Tags: regression, cross-validation, ordinal-data, error

I am using repeated 10-fold CV to calculate the accuracy of my ordinal regression model. I have 6 predictors, 10 ordered response categories, and a total of 1166 data points.

For the ordinal model, I have defined accuracy as *1 - loss*, with *loss* being a simple linear function of the distance between observed and predicted classes, assuming classes are equidistant.

I chose the number of repetitions for the 10-fold CV by examining the stability of the results as advised [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82546/how-many-times-should-we-repeat-a-k-fold-cv), and decided to use 5 repetitions.

Finally, I am using this measure of accuracy to compare the quality of the predictions given different predictor values. More precisely, I have a range of possible storm wave conditions and associated parameters, 10 levels of increasing damage for ships caught in the storm, and I am  looking to find the wave conditions which have more likely triggered the damage. So I run the model for each one and compare the accuracy.

My problem is, for all conditions tested my accuracy is suspiciously high i.e. > 80%. I am not expecting this kind of accuracy given the quality of some of my predictors (for example, the wave velocity has been estimated numerically on a coarse grid with a number of simplifying assumptions).

Also, there is not much variation in accuracy between the model outputs for different wave conditions, maximum +/- 1%. Again I would have expected more than this.

I am wondering if there is something I am missing here, regarding my estimation of accuracy. What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Is one of your categories particularly common?

Comment: Also, its probably better to use your likelihood function to assess accuracy.  I think its something like cross entropy for categorical models.  Take "residual" to be $-\log (\hat {p}_{ki}) $ where k is the observed response category for the ith oobservation, and $\hat {p}_{ki} $ is the model probability that the ith observation is in the kth category.

Comment: Actually yes, 65% of the data lies in the last category so I guess particularly common...

Comment: Also I found this article http://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/why-you-should-use-cross-entropy-error-instead-of-classification-error-or-mean-squared-error-for-neural-network-classifier-training/   on cross entropy but could you suggest maybe some more official sources I could check? ie. papers?

Comment: What would be the effect of having a particularly common category on accuracy results?

Comment: Well, if I just predict the most common category, I'll get 65% accuracy - so in this case 80% is not necessarily a large gain.

Comment: You can check whether this messes up your results (and the classifier) by looking at accuracy for each class (in medical context this is sensitivity).

Comment: Another common problem that causes suspiciously goodlooking CV results is a "leak" between training and test data, e.g. pre-processing calculations that are done on the whole data set (centering, scaling, etc.)