# Is cross validation a tool for developing performance metrics or final models?

Tags: cross-validation, predictive-models, prediction, accuracy, model-evaluation

If you cannot acquire a workable *test* data-set to test a model, you can use cross validation as an alternative to validate the model.

However, I'm unsure of the true *end* purpose of cross validation...

Is CV useful for simply generating a [performance metric](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148698/80624) by providing a way to test your model? Or is it a means to creating a final model?

Put differently: do I use my "best" model from whichever given fold of the CV process (i.e., the "best" model using *some* partition of the data) as my final model? Or do I perform CV, report my performance metric, and then re-create the model using *ALL* of my available data to create a *final* model?

Answer (score 2):

#### Is CV useful for simply generating a performance metric by providing a way to test your model? Or is it a means to creating a final model?

For both. It generates performance metrics to test your model (perhaps, on different parameters).

It is also a means of creating the final model, because you would "often" use cross-validation to choose the best parameters of the model. You then use the best parameters on all of the data to generate the final model. However, while reporting please report the cross-validation error.

Comment: What exactly is "cross-validation error"? How is it calculated?

Comment: You train a model on training data. Use that model to predict on the test data. The performance of the model on the test data is called cross-validation error.

Comment: Ah. So it's just relative to what it's reporting performance of (i.e., the model's ability to predict values for the test data). It could theoretically consist of MSE, RMSE, AUC, MAE, etc. , then?

Comment: Yes! Metric is your choice and depends on the task at hand and also on the data. Cross-validation error is used more generically; it may be accuracy or AUC or accuracy or similar in clasification and MAE or MSE or similar in regression.

Comment: Error and accuracy are not the same; they are the flip sides of the same coin.

Answer (score 0):

From Zhang 1997:

> The purpose of data splitting is to choose
>   the best model or to study model stability and predictive
>   performance. The final estimation of the model parameters
>   should come from the entire data set (Myers, 1990; Shao,
>   1993).

Myers RH. 1990. Classical and modern regression with applications. 2nd
Edn. Boston: PWS-KENT Publishing Company.

Shao J. 1993. Linear model selection by cross-validation. Journal of
American Statistical Association 88: 486±494.

ZHANG, LIANJUN. 1997. Cross-validation of non-linear growth functions for modelling tree height–diameter relationships. Annals of Botany 79.3: 251-257.